# How to select unaggregated records from table ordering by count of aggragate query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a hard time phrasing the question so here's an example. I have query that gets me records for a given list grouped by their parent barcode and ordered descending.

```
select count(*),parent_bc from table where column_name IN (...) group by 
parent_bc;

COUNT(*)  parent_bc
9         14018091
8         14018030
5         14018098
3         14018027
```

Now, for the same table, I want to get the records (unaggregated) but order by the count from the query above. Eg, "SELECT columns FROM tbl WHERE (...) ORDER BY ... ?

Is this even possible in a single query?

Comment: Forgot to add that it's Oracle 12c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `count` function.

```
select count(*) over(partition by parent_bc) as cnt_per_bc,t.* 
from table t
where column_name IN (...)
order by cnt_per_bc desc
```

Comment: This was perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want:

```
select count(*), parent_bc
from table
where column_name IN (...) 
order by count(*) over (partition by parent_bc) desc, parent_bc;
```

Note that this adds the `parent_bc` as a second key.  When there are ties, this keeps the values for each `parent_bc` together.